# How do I add specific values on multiple rows of a csv file from different starting points?

Tags: linux, csv, sqr

I used an SQR to create a comma delimited .csv file with multiple rows of data. On each row there are four different sets of data. One set is a monetary value. I am trying to use a Linux script to pull the monetary value of each row off the .csv file and get a total monetary value for all rows of monetary value data. My problem is that the starting point of each monetary value varies depending information written prior to the monetary amount. Also, the ending point for each monetary amount varies as well. I am not sure how to approach this. I need assistance in writing some code that can pull off only the monetary values of each row and add it together with the next row and so on. Below is a sample of how the .csv file looks. The first column is the business unit, the second column is the project id, the third column is the monetary value, and the fourth is the project approver's name. Can you please assist.

```
EDJ,50007556,587850,"Project Approver"
EDJ,50007557,348462.25,"Project Approver"
CAN,50002657,8245.75,"Project Approver"
EJTC,00000010,198746.30,"Project Approver"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cut` to select a column in a delimited file:

```
cut -f3 -d, FILE # comma as the delimiter, third column
```

To sum the values, I would use Perl:

```
cut -f3 -d, FILE | perl -lne '$s += $_ }{ print $s'
```

But, Perl can handle the columns itself, so `cut` is not needed:

```
perl -F, -ane '$s += $F[2] }{ print $s' FILE
```

Comment: When you do the cut does that give you the first position of the 3rd column? If so, to store the value in the 3rd column would I have to also do a cut on the fourth column then pull in the value on the line between the two positions?

MONEYSTART=$(echo $WHEREAMTIS | cut -d "," -f3)
MONEYLENGTH=$(echo $WHEREAMTIS | cut -d "," -f4)
WHEREAMTIS=$(echo $WHEREAMTIS | cut -d "," -f2)

I don't think I am fully grasping the concept. Could you explain with using Linux bash solely?

Comment: @DrewDrawsKelly: `cut` gives you the value of the column, no positions involved.